# What do I need to mix four microphones to PC, monitor all mics and PC output

Tags: microphone, mixer, monitoring, lavalier

Ok, so we do recordings of games all at one computer (four of us).

We have 4 lav mics that have TRRS 3.5mm jacks (so we can use them on our smartphones for other things).

We have 4 pairs of earbuds with TRS 3.5mm jacks.

What we need to be able to do is mix all the mics and send them to my PC, at the same time have the mics sound and the output from my PC sent to the earbuds so we can hear the game sound and monitor our mics.

Our current solution is a Blue Yeti with a 3.5mm cable plugged into the monitoring port split with three splitters to our earbuds, then we select the Yeti as the default device in Windows and it sends game sound through the monitoring port, letting us hear ourselves and the game.

We want to switch to using 4 lav mics as the yeti sounds a bit distant.

Ideally I'd like to be able to adjust our earbud volumes and mic volumes all separately but I'm assuming that would need 8 channels on a mixer.

The absolute minimum we need is to have all the mics combined to one 3.5mm plug using splitters, and all the earbuds combined to one 3.5mm jack using splitters then send mic sound to my PC, PC sound and mic sound to the earbuds.

I don't understand mixers very well, would this:
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Behringer-XENYX-Q502USB-5-Input-Mixer-with-Mic-Preamp-USB-/291305345697?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item43d326d2a1

Do the job?

We don't need any kind of amp for the headphones because they're just earbuds.

Sorry if this question is confusing but thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a slightly bigger mixer for that, e.g. BEHRINGER XENYX Q1202USB:
[image: BEHRINGER XENYX Q1202USB]

and then some minijack -> xlr adapters for your jack lavs, like this one:

[image: rode-vxlr-minijack-to-xlr-adaptor]

I am not aware of any TRRS to XLR adapters, so you probably also need the [SC3](http://www.rode.com/accessories/sc3) adapter. If you're skilled with a soldering tool, it is rather easy to make. Just buy a female TRRS and a short XLR cable, cut off one end and put on the TRRS. You can see the wiring of the TRRS [here](http://wpc.660d.edgecastcdn.net/80660D/downloads/sc3_datasheet.pdf).

The mixer will allow you to add four different stereo sources (e.q. four computers) at channel 5/6 - 11/12, via stereo mini jack -> split mono jack.

There is a combined record output (the top phonos) and you have one combined phones output too. Use something like the BEHRINGER MICROAMP HA400 to split that - it also gives you separate volume control:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work. What happens if I plug a TRRS lav mic into a TRS extender cable? Will it still work? And do I need to find minijack to xlr adapters that are specifically TRRS 3.5mm to XLR?

Comment: It will probably work, but let me check - what model is that lavaliere mic?

Comment: Rode Smartlav+ http://www.rode.com/microphones/smartlav-plus

Comment: Updated the post - it seems you CANNOT use a standard minijack to xlr converter alone, you need a special TRRS to TRS/TS converter first (the SC2).

Comment: I can't seem to get anything from the microphone to be picked up by the mixer. If I plug in the output from my computer as a microphone it can be heard but the mics themselves do nothing, even with maximum gain.

Comment: I just noticed that with my phone playing audio into a 3.5mm to 1/4" adapter which is plugged into a 1/4" to XLR adapter, that with the 3.5mm jack plugged all the way in, it sounds really quiet and weird, but when I unplug it slightly it gets hugely louder and sounds much better. What's going on???

Comment: Do you use that sc3 adapter?

Comment: It hasn't arrived yet but I was testing with the mic from a headset.

Comment: And your head set has a standard trs minijack from the mic?

Comment: Yes. And I tried it on my PC and recorded sound fine.

Comment: I figured it out. We were using stereo inputs and the inputs are balanced. The manual (I should have read it more carefully before) says to use unbalanced inputs, they have to be mono, or bridge the ring and sleeve. Or in the case of XLR, bridge pins 1 and 3. I bridged 1 and 3 on the XLR adapters and it sounds normal even with all the connectors fully plugged in.

Comment: I still can't get the headset mic to do ANYTHING when plugged into the mixer...

Comment: You kinda lost me with the setup ;-) Are you soldering the XLR connector yourself? Are you using a different mic than described in the question? I think perhaps you should make a new question with the setup you have now, perhaps supply a picture of the mixer with the headset mic and computer plugged in